# how to read a smaller chunk of a bigger file as byte array and treat it as a video or audio file in java android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have one big file (I used a hex editor to simply put a few .mp4 and .mp3 files next to each other and saved them as one big ~500mb raw data file and recorded each file's starting offset/index and their lengths, i.e. file Sizes) now I want to put that big file in android external storage and read one of these videos or audio files from it.
 I know I can create a temporary file in context.getCacheDir(); and write this smaller(30-50MiB) byte array chunk to it and simply play the file in my videoView, 
but i want to read this file without creating a temporary file and deleting it each time i get in/out of that activity.

i probably need to define a File and save that byte array to it, and feed that File to my mediaPlayer as the data source without writing it to a cache file. how can i do this? (please answer with a code snippet/example)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that if you just switch to a different player.

Use [`ExoPlayer`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) to play, and create a custom `DataSource`. In this [`DataSource`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DataSource.html) you can start reading bytes from wherever and feed it to the `ExoPlayer` to be played.

However, it should be noted that some video file containers add some meta data at the end of the file, while others add it at the start. And this meta-data is required to play them.